# Generate all permutations of fixed length where the elements come from two different sets

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

Is there any function in python `itertools` where all the permutations of numbers that satisfy certain criteria need to be generated.

(a,b,c,d)

- a and d: comes from `set 1 = {1,2,3}`
- b and c: comes from `set 2`, where the number of elements set 2 is 196.
- Th permutation need to be with replacement.

So a and b should take only values from set 1 and b and c should take values only from set 2. How can I generate all the permutaitons with the said restrictions

I am aware how to generate permutation using `itertools` to generate enetries with permutation. But I am having problem when it comes to taking items from two sets

Comment: But I do not see how these are permutations...

Comment: So… you need to generate permutations for both sets and compute the cartesian product? (and arrange the result a bit) It's not very clear from your question ^^

Comment: what does mean `ie |set 2| is 196` ?

Comment: @spectras - THe product actually worked thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpreted your text correctly, the following code should be what you are looking for:

```
import itertools
set1 = [1,2,3]
set2 = [4,5]

for i in itertools.permutations(set1, 2):
    for j in itertools.permutations(set2, 2):
        print("({},{},{},{})".format(i[0], j[0], j[1], i[1]))
```

Prints

```
(1,4,5,2)
(1,5,4,2)
(1,4,5,3)
(1,5,4,3)
(2,4,5,1)
(2,5,4,1)
(2,4,5,3)
(2,5,4,3)
(3,4,5,1)
(3,5,4,1)
(3,4,5,2)
(3,5,4,2)
```

As @spectras suggests, a product is more elegant:

```
p1 = itertools.permutations(set1, 2)
p2 = itertools.permutations(set2, 2)

for i in itertools.product(p1, p2):
     print(i[0][0], i[1][0], i[1][1], i[0][1])
```

Comment: As @spectras suggested, another way is to use product three times and then reordering the entries. But this one works as well.